# Can Galaxybase Single Server be installed on the cloud?

Tags: graph-databases

Can Galaxybase Single Server be installed on the cloud? How to download and install? I would love a detailed instruction about that, thanks a lot.

I've searched [the official website](https://www.galaxybase.com/), but I didn't find any technical documentation about it, nor the configuration of the environment to be deployed on the cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely yes. We have [a live playback course](https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1iY4y1F7Hn/?share_source=copy_web&vd_source=ba3f98c6c6ff58cc02c9960ab3d68d2c) about it which includes detailed instructions on how to download and install. Please take a look :)